# Will dismantling year 1 Thorn give me the schematic?

Tags: destiny

I've just managed to get an Xbox One to play year 3 content and I've heard that dismantling a year 1 Gjallarhorn will give you a schematic that let's you build the year 3 version.

Can the same be done with a year 1 Thorn to save all the palaver with the exotic bounty or do I have to do it the old fashioned way?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're asking:

Will breaking down the Y1 *Thorn* give the schematic for the Y3 or do I have to do the bounty / exotic quest means of procurement?

No. Y1 Thorn doesn't give a schematic. You'll have to obtain it the old fashioned way.

Answer (score 0):

Only your original Khvostov will give you a schematic if you dismantle it.

To get the Y3 Thorn, you need to do the weekly bounties from Shiro-4.  When you turn them in, you have a chance to get the new Thorn quest.